# Time remaining for the next run

Tags: cron, timestamps

I need to calculate the time remaining for the next run of a specific job in my Cron Schedule, I've a Cron with jobs having frequencies of per hour, thrice a day etc, no jobs running on specific days/dates hence just HH:MM:SS is concerned, also I do not have right to  check `/var/spool/cron/` in my RHEL.
If some job starts at `9:30`,

```
30 9 * * * /some/job.sh
-bash-3.2$ date +"%H:%M"
13:52
```

I'd need output as, `19 Hours and 38 Minutes` How would I be knowing the total time until next run occurs from current system time? Calculation of seconds is concerned only around the job time.

Comment: [systemd-timers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers) can do this- too bad they need recent linux support and root on RHEL...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`cron` doesn't know when a job is going to fire. All it does is every minute, go over all the `crontab` entries and fire those that match `"$(date '+%M %H %d %m %w')"`.

What you could do is generate all those timestamps for every minute from now to 49 hours from now (account for DST change), do the matching by hand (the tricky part) and report the first matching one.

Or you could use the [croniter](http://github.com/kiorky/croniter) `python` module:

```
python -c '
from croniter import croniter
from datetime import datetime
iter = croniter("3 9 * * *", datetime.now())
print(iter.get_next(datetime))'
```

For the delay:

```
$ faketime 13:52:00 python -c '
from croniter import croniter
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.now()
iter = croniter("30 9 * * *", d)
print iter.get_next(datetime) - d'
19:37:59.413956
```

Beware of potential bugs around DST changes though:

```
$ faketime '2015-03-28 01:01:00' python -c '
from croniter import croniter
from datetime import datetime
iter = croniter("1 1 * * *", datetime.now())
print iter.get_next(datetime)'
2015-03-29 02:01:00

$ FAKETIME_FMT=%s faketime -f 1445734799 date
Sun 25 Oct 01:59:59 BST 2015
$ FAKETIME_FMT=%s faketime -f 1445734799  python -c '
from croniter import croniter
from datetime import datetime
iter = croniter("1 1 * * *", datetime.now())
print iter.get_next(datetime)'
2015-10-25 01:01:00

$ FAKETIME_FMT=%s faketime -f 1445734799 python -c '
from croniter import croniter
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.now()
iter = croniter("1 1 * * *", d)
print iter.get_next(datetime) - d'
-1 day, 23:01:01
```

`cron` itself takes care of that by avoiding to run the job twice if the time has gone backward, or run skipped jobs after the shift if the time has gone forward.

Comment: This surely should have helped, if I could have been able to use croniter repo, reason being its my workplace machine, so any workout without python? Have thought of manually doing it but there are so much scenarios/conditions which would take time

Comment: @Keys you don't have to install that module (or python) in a root - owned location. So you don't have to be root.

Comment: What about this dynamic version of Python ? https://hastebin.com/eturofobif.py

Answer (score 8):

As it happens, the `%T` format of the `printf` builtin of the `ksh93` shell does support [standard crontab specifications](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/crontab.html#tag_20_25_07) as input.

```
$ ksh93 -c 'printf "%(%F %T)T\n" now "30 9 * * *"'
2017-11-07 17:06:41
2017-11-08 09:30:00
```

So you can get the delta in seconds there with:

```
#! /bin/ksh93 -
crontab_line='30 9 * * *'
delta=$(($(printf '(%(%s)T - %(%s)T) / 60' "$crontab_line" now)))
echo "Next run in $((delta/60)) hours and $((delta%60)) minutes."
```

Note that it doesn't support the extensions sometimes supported by some (most) cron implementations, such as `*/5` or month/day names or 7 as the day of the week, or `@reboot`, `@hourly`, etc.

Comment: That's a pretty good answer, however only works when the cron schedule is fixed. If it contains recurring placeholders, such as `*/5`, then the printf of ksh93 will fail.

Comment: @ClaudioKuenzler, yes it only supports the [standard crontab syntax](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/crontab.html), not the extensions sometimes supported by some (most) cron implementations, such as your */5 or month/day names or 7 as the day of the week, or `@reboot`, `@hourly`, etc. `*/5` can be written standardly 0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55  though

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas not just that, the ksh implementation isn't following the POSIX standard either. "0 0 23 * 0" means "Every Sunday and Every 23rd day-of-month" in the POSIX spec, but in ksh it means "Every 23rd day-of-month if it is a Sunday".

Answer (score 2):

### One way, using a dedicated [Perl's script](https://metacpan.org/release/PKENT/Schedule-Cron-Events-1.8/source/cron_event_predict.plx)

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use lib './lib';
use Schedule::Cron::Events;
use Getopt::Std;
use Time::Local;
use vars qw($opt_f $opt_h $opt_p);
getopts('p:f:h');

if ($opt_h) { usage(); }
my $filename = shift || usage();

my $future = 2;
if (defined $opt_f) { $future = $opt_f; }
my $past = 0;
if (defined $opt_p) { $past = $opt_p; }

open (IN, '<$filename') || die "Unable to open '$filename' for read: $!";
while(<IN>) {
    my $obj = new Schedule::Cron::Events($_) || next;
    chomp;
    print "# Original line: $_\n";

    if ($future) {
        for (1..$future) {
                my $date = localtime( timelocal($obj->nextEvent) );
                print "$date - predicted future event\n";
        }
    }
    $obj->resetCounter;
    if ($past) {
        for (1..$past) {
                my $date = localtime( timelocal($obj->previousEvent) );
                print "$date - predicted past event\n";
        }
    }
    print "\n";
}
close IN;


sub usage {
    print qq{
SYNOPSIS

$0 [ -h ] [ -f number ] [ -p number ] <crontab-filename>

Reads the crontab specified and iterates over every line in it, predicting when 
each cron event in the crontab will run. Defaults to predicting the next 2 events.

    -h - show this help
    -f - how many events predited in the future. Default is 2
    -p - how many events predicted for the past. Default is 0.

EXAMPLE

$0 -f 2 -p 2 ~/my.crontab

\$Revision\$

};
    exit;
}

=pod

=head1 NAME

cron_event_predict - Reads a crontab file and predicts when event will/would have run

=head1 SYNOPSIS

cron_event_predict.plx [ -h ] [ -f number ] [ -p number ] <crontab-filename>

=head1 DESCRIPTION

A simple utility program mainly written to provide a worked example of how to use the module,
but also of some use in understanding complex or unfamiliar crontab files.

Reads the crontab specified and iterates over every line in it, predicting when 
each cron event in the crontab will run. Defaults to predicting the next 2 events.

These are the command line arguments:

    -h - show this help
    -f - how many events predited in the future. Default is 2
    -p - how many events predicted for the past. Default is 0.

Here's an example, showing the default of the next 2 predicted occurences of the each cron job:

    dev~/src/cronevent > ./cron_event_predict.plx ~/bin/crontab
    # Original line: 1-56/5 * * * * /usr/local/mrtg-2/bin/mrtg /home/admin/mrtg/mrtg.cfg
    Thu Sep 26 00:41:00 2002 - predicted future event
    Thu Sep 26 00:46:00 2002 - predicted future event
    
    # Original line: 34 */2 * * * /home/analog/analogwrap.bash > /dev/null
    Thu Sep 26 02:34:00 2002 - predicted future event
    Thu Sep 26 04:34:00 2002 - predicted future event
    
    # Original line: 38 18 * * * /home/admin/bin/allpodscript.bash > /dev/null
    Thu Sep 26 18:38:00 2002 - predicted future event
    Fri Sep 27 18:38:00 2002 - predicted future event

And here's an example showing past events too:

    dev~/src/cronevent > ./cron_event_predict.plx -f 1 -p 3 ~/bin/crontab
    # Original line: 1-56/5 * * * * /usr/local/mrtg-2/bin/mrtg /home/admin/mrtg/mrtg.cfg
    Thu Sep 26 00:41:00 2002 - predicted future event
    Thu Sep 26 00:36:00 2002 - predicted past event
    Thu Sep 26 00:31:00 2002 - predicted past event
    Thu Sep 26 00:26:00 2002 - predicted past event
    
    # Original line: 34 */2 * * * /home/analog/analogwrap.bash > /dev/null
    Thu Sep 26 02:34:00 2002 - predicted future event
    Thu Sep 26 00:34:00 2002 - predicted past event
    Wed Sep 25 22:34:00 2002 - predicted past event
    Wed Sep 25 20:34:00 2002 - predicted past event
    
    # Original line: 38 18 * * * /home/admin/bin/allpodscript.bash > /dev/null
    Thu Sep 26 18:38:00 2002 - predicted future event
    Wed Sep 25 18:38:00 2002 - predicted past event
    Tue Sep 24 18:38:00 2002 - predicted past event
    Mon Sep 23 18:38:00 2002 - predicted past event
```

### Usage

```
crontab -l | perl cron_event_predict.plx /dev/stdin
```

or

```
crontab -l > /tmp/crontab
perl cron_event_predict.plx /tmp/crontab
```

### Example

```
# Original line: 10,16,30,50 * * * * /path/to/script.bash
Sat Jan  7 08:50:00 2023 - predicted future event
Sat Jan  7 09:10:00 2023 - predicted future event
```